# android how to write onclick event of edittext

Tags: android, events, click, android-edittext

I have a editText contianing text Enter ur name..   so i want to when user just click on that editText then the text disappear and editText should be empty and user can write anything their.    so how can i do like this.  plz give me ans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your requirement you don't need onClick event listener.

try this

```
 <EditText
                android:hint="Enter you name"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
```

or from java code

```
editText.setHint("Enter you name");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 final EditText edittxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
    edittxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            if (hasFocus == true)
            {
                if (edittxt.getText().toString().compareTo("Your hint") == 0) // default text
                {
                    edittxt.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        ((EditText)v).setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:hint = "text that you want the user to be assisted with while typing"` is used for this feature.

This works well with EditText, `autocompleteText` view as well both in android and monodroid.